# Data structure to represent an indoor map

Tags: android, performance, memory, data-structures

Let's say I have an image that represents a map of an indoor place. On this map, certain zones are "allowed" and others not. I then get periodically an set of coordinates `(x,y)` and need to check if they are in an "allowed" zone or not.

At the moment, I am representing this map by an `boolean[][] map` variable, where `true` means allowed. To check, I then just check the value of `map[x][y]`

However, the images that I am representing can become quite large, let's say maximum 5000x5000 pixels. As a consequence, my `map` variable becomes too large in memory (25MB in this case assuming a `boolean` takes roughly 1 byte)

Is there a better data structure out there for my problem? I've been thinking for a while now but I can't see anything that would take less space.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common scenario for such situation is to use an array/`List` of `Rect` structures. You then define, that such a rectangle defines an area that is "allowed".

Then, given a point `(x, y)` you simply iterate over the array/list and check if the point lies inside any of the rectangles in the collection. You can simply use `Rect.contains(x,y)` for this. You answer `true` if any `Rect` contains the point in question and `false` otherwise.

That should give you a very decent performance/memory consumption ratio. It's commonly used in applications such as yours assuming the "zones" are rectangular (or each zone can be expressed as a union of - ideally - small number of rectangles).

Another alternative (provided that rectangles are not an option) would be to use a discreet polygons to represent the zones. If this is feasible, you could use a simple algorithm presented here: http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/ It lets you test whether a given point is inside (even very complex) polygon in time `O(n)` where `n` is the number of all vertexes of all polygons defining the zones of your map.

If your zones are *very* scattered (i.e. it's hard to represent them using rectangles of even polygons) then you probably have no other simple choice. What you could do is to (for example) create an array which would contain row-allowance information. For each row you would have an array `int[]` in which every `int` would contain 32 bits each representing `boolean` values for consecutive columns. This is very similar to what you already have, but you would have a memory footprint smaller by a factor of 8, because each value would take only one bit and not a whole byte.

Comment: I like your idea, the only downfall is the added complexity to build those Rect objects. The data comes from a csv file containing rows of 0s and 1s. I guess I could use a recursive algorithm to build those Rects..., not trivial though!

Comment: I see. But you know - if the data comes in such a painfull-to-process format then I suspect you have no alternative really. I personally would go with the `Rect`/polygon method since most planar maps can be expressed using them. An algorithm would pay off given the amount of memory saved. Remember - Android devices have 16/24/32MB memory limit/process!

Comment: ok thanks a lot, guess I'm going to bite the bullet and write the algorithm to generate the poylgons.